# Statistics: Finding the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (or forecasting error)

Tags: statistics

So I made a model for a set of sea level data, and wanted to see how accurate my model was. I then decided to use the Mean Absolute Percentage Error formula.

I got less than 1% and my model does fit pretty well, but was wondering if it might be too small of an error?

Also, is the formula:

Actual-Model / Actual --> (Value x 100)/the number of data

Because on some sites, it looked like you don't have to divide the percentage by the number of data?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct to me. Although you need absolute brackets around the numerator. Part of the problem with MAPE is interpreting the result - if your data is not very volatile then 1% may be a perfectly reasonable result, but for volatile data you'd probably think twice. You definitely need to divide by the number of sample points, because you're calculating the mean. Also, you don't want your result to depend on the number of sample points you've included in the sum.